# Currency metabolites vs. current metabolites: What's the right term?

Tags: metabolism, terminology

I have seen the two terms `currency metabolite` and `current metabolite` used interchangeably. Is there a consensus on which is the right term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currency** refers to anything that is used in any circumstances, as a medium of exchange [1]. That's why [ATP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate) and NAD are considered as currency metabolites [2]. So currency metabolite can be used for any metabolite that has multiple uses in different reactions/pathways.

**Current** refers to something that is prevalent at the present time [3]. So current metabolite is used to refer a metabolite that is already available for a specific reaction/pathway and doesn't need to undergo supplementary transformations to fit for that specific reaction.

The same metabolite can be simultaneously a currency metabolite and a current metabolite for a specific situation.

---

References:

1. Wikipedia contributors, "Currency," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Currency&oldid=611672968 (accessed July 12, 2014).
2. Gerlee P, Lizana L, Sneppen K. [Pathway identification by network pruning in the metabolic network of Escherichia coli.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19808881) Bioinformatics. 2009 Dec 15;25(24):3282-8. doi: [10.1093/bioinformatics/btp575](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btp575). PubMed PMID: 19808881.
3. The Free Dictionary by Farlex. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/current

Comment: I wonder if 'current metabolite' is not simply a mistake? The second usage does not sound idiomatic.